# Halt transition until css transition is complete

Tags: css, ember.js, routes, transition

I'm trying to pause a transition until a css transition has complete and then allow the transition to continue.

```
willTransition(transition) {
    transition.abort();
    var self = this;
    Ember.$('.event-item-component:not(.bidding)').removeClass('animate');
    Ember.$('.event-item-component:not(.bidding)').first().one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(){
        console.log('ready');
        transition.retry();
    })
}
```

But the `retry()` seems to not be doing what I anticipated it doing. How would I go about this?

**UPDATE:**

Trying the ember Run loop seems promising here as mentioned by `Victor Nitu` here is the code I'm attempting now

```
actions: {
    didTransition() {
        Ember.run.schedule('afterRender',function(){
            console.log('did render');
            Ember.$('.event-item-component:not(.bidding)').addClass('animate');
        });
    },
    willTransition(transition) {
        Ember.run.schedule('actions',function(){
            console.log('about to leave');
            Ember.$('.event-item-component:not(.bidding)').removeClass('animate');
        })
    }
}
```

However the removal of the animate class is not happening before the transition completes, the animation needs to complete before the transition attempts to happen so there is no jumping happening in the animation or UI

Comment: Does "ready" get logged at all?

Comment: Might be a bug cause the code looks straight forward. What version of ember are u using?

Comment: Yes ready does get called, although it is getting called 3 times? I am on ember `2.2.0`

Comment: Try using the Ember Run Loop https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/applications/run-loop/

Comment: Oh, and http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_schedule

Comment: I would advise trying https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire

Comment: @VictorNitu the run loop seems promising, I updated my question to show the code I have attempted and am still getting a similar result.